# unable to nunit test my log4net wrapper class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, nunit, log4net

I wrote a wrapper class for log4net. This wrapper class works correctly with asp.net web application. And now I am trying to test my wrapper class methods using NUNIT. 
In wrapper class project, I set "Copy Local" to True for log4net DLL. Both NUNIT project and wrapper class are using log4net 1.2.10.0.

This wrapper class works correctly with my separate asp.net web project but some how does not work with my nunit test project.

When I try to run a basic test, I get the following exception

> System.BadImageFormatException : Could not load file or assembly
>   'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. An
>   attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I am running these test within Resharper for VS2010

**UPDATE**

Just updated my wrapper  and test projects with log4net.dll version 1.2.11.0 and every thing starts to work magically!!! I don't know how this latest version fix this problem where 1.2.10.0 kept failing

Comment: you are loading wrong image, like using x64 on x86 architecture or vice-versa

Comment: updated my question. How come that log4net.dll works with asp.net web project? please let me know.

Comment: If you add a reference to log4net from your test project does it still give you the error?

Comment: Just adding the reference in test project does not give any error. When I run the test, then I get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are loading a 32-bit DLL on a 64-bit system.  You shall build your tests DLL targetting a 32-bit architecture.

Process is described in existing question:  [Using a 32 bit dll on a 64 bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711748/using-a-32-bit-dll-on-a-64-bit-machine)

Comment: why does this wrapper class with log4net(32bit DLL) work with my asp.net web application?

Comment: maybe 32-bit compatibility is enabled in IIS app pool (that makes 32-bit DLLs work) or maybe log4net is ok with its bits and there's another DLL or app which is damaging the 64-bit chain.  Did you get the same results with NUnit, for instance, to test a different environment?